# Natural structural formation of matter

Tags: physics

In nature we see natural pattern formations when a material forms an organised structure within a less dense material in order to fill the space in the most efficient form. Such as hexagonal and octagonal formations in clouds and surface bubbles on water.

My question is based on the natural formation of gas into a structural pattern and if a geometric pattern formation needs a hard boundary in order for it to be uniform?

For example bubbles and clouds can form into an organised uniform pattern but at the outer edges the shapes will become less uniform and larger but bubbles on the surface of water that is within a container will fill the space in a uniform pattern either filling the surface or forming a pattern bubble voids uniformly.

It seems that no boundary leads to a structural breakdown of the pattern but a boundary creates the uniform pattern, is this always the case? The reason I ask this is so that I can design large scale matter distribution for my story's universe.

Comment: Are all these bubbles the same size? Are we completely filling these spaces (bubbles will lump together, leaving open gaps that aren't covered if not)? Can we get more context, as the last sentence seems off. Soap bubbles of similar size will hold on to each other via surface tension, allowing the formations of stable patterns in the absence of boundaries just fine, so long as the bubbles make physical contact.

Comment: Hexagonal, and octagonal formations in clouds? I don't know of any clouds with such a regular structure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about building an imaginary world. Perhaps try Physics SE.

Comment: @DangerLake which sentence seems off, the very last one? the space is not filled, hence the bubble voids being the structure not bubbles themselves.

Comment: @Daron Of course it is an imaginary world, it is my story and its universe. It is based on real physics but isn't all Sci-Fi unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @sphennings I haven't witnessed any myself but a google search for hexagonal forms in nature came up with some cloud images, I chose clouds and bubbles as the example because they are the closest to what I am trying to find out.

Comment: What is a boundary? If you fill the universe with a lightweight gas, it will coalesce into ... stars and planets. It creates boundaries using gravity!

Comment: @sdfgeoff I used the term "hard boundary" as something either of higher density or energy than the two materials or a causal boundary and a soft boundary would just be the line where the higher density ends. They will coalesce without a boundary but the structure seen in simulations and some theories show a uniform pattern which occurs after initial supercluster and galaxy formations.

Answer (score 4):

**Keyword Entropy**

The general phenomenon you are referring to is the increase in entropy in a closed system. Entropy doesn't have a formal meaning (or rather it has many different formal meanings) but usually refers to how *randomly* a bunch of stuff is arranged.

If you take a bunch of particles in a box in any arrangement -- for example put a bunch of hot particles at the top and a bunch of cold ones at the bottom -- then after a while you will find all the particles are the same temperature.  There are no islands of high pressure. Entropy has increased.

The particles are now *random* in the sense that if you were to choose an arrangement at random from all the possible arrangements, then most of them will look like this unless you zoom in super close. There are relatively few arrangements where for example half the particles are at the top, half at the bottom, and they are all rushing towards the middle. But there are kajillions of arrangements where it looks like nothing is happening.

Another thing entropy means is the conversion of energy in a closed box into heat energy. Bubbles want to form what are called **minimal surfaces**. These tend to be repeating. To get the bubbles to form anything else you need some energy acting one them. As all the energy turns into heat there is less left over and you get repeating patterns. This does not happen so much when there is no boundary and energy can enter and leave the box into the surrounding air.

As for the arrangement of matter in the universe -- it is far from uniform in the real universe. Matter coalesces into galaxies rather than spreading out. The galaxies form superclusters which form filements. Even the observable univere as a whole is far from uniform

[image]

Of course you should not take the above image at face value. After all there are no labels on the axes. The "continents" of denser matter might be artefacts of the display method.

**Your Homework:** The above is a famous image. Find out what display method is being used.

**Your Homework:** Should we expect the observable universe to behave like a closed box in the first place?

Comment: The universe is homogeneous at the largest scales and in simulations, I agree in looking at superclusters and void shapes it is not uniform but there are no areas where it is sparse or more concentrated at the largest scales. So a boundary does seem necessary for uniform pattern you say.

Comment: @JarredJones The CMB image has big red islands and also big blue islands. Red means more matter and blue means less matter.

Comment: I am very familiar with the CMB to the point that I know which densities are the current superclusters.

Answer (score 2):

**The boundary governing the interaction is between matter and not-matter.**

[image: pan with bubbles]

I washed my greasy pan for you, Jarred Jones.  And I did not rinse it as much as I usually do.  Behold: residual bubbles.  These bubbles agglomerate over time.  It does not have to do with the boundary of the pan.  It has to do with the affinity of bubble for bubble which I think here has to do with surface tension.

But lo!  Sometimes matter does not agglomerate!  I sprinkled flour in the pan.  Some of the flour made it to the bottom.  But where the powder hit, it spread into hazy smudges.  The flour did not want to clump up.  If you are smoking in the bathroom right now, tap your ash into the toilet.  It spreads fast.  These particles repel each other, I think possibly because they all carry a similar charge.

[image]

I am reminded of the CGI used to make zombie effects for the movie World War Z.
https://youtu.be/tvoUMH9Ghpo?t=21

They used a computer model in which the CGI human entities usually keep a space between themselves and other entities.  For the zombies they reversed that to make the zombies clump up into scary hordes.

Matter in the early universe was not governed by extrinsic boundaries but by the interaction between particles - initially gravity and then other attractive and repulsive forces.  You can model your matter similarly.

Comment: You washed your pan!? Heaven forbid a cast iron pan become totally clean and lose its season! But really, there are a lot of deep (and to my knowledge unanswered) questions as to why we see the structures we do. Yes, repulsive and attractive forces, but... Why clusters? Is it *really* dark matter messing with rotational rates? Where is the antimatter and anti-galaxies? And so on until you are a PhD astrophysicist/theoretical physicist...

Comment: This is what got me thinking about the pattern when I left a pot to soak haha, but we must be eating different things because I got a much more defined  pattern of bubble scum and voids.

Answer (score 2):

## No Boundary Needed For Patterns

We see plenty of things which form patterns in conditions we consider infinite. Consider these examples at various scales, which form without any noticable presence of a box:

- Filings if iron in a magnetic field
- Van Allen and similar radiation belts forming around special sources of magnetism
- Accretion disks around black holes
- Galactic spirals and arms
- Bubbles minimize surface area and make various geometric shapes when enough run into each other.
- Precipitates (like rock candy) form in essentially boundless conditions. (The nucleation points matter here).

It just depends on the factors driving the formation (or not) for patterns. You can explain these with Newtonian physics, favorable energetic reactions, or what-have-you, but it comes down to one conclusion: patterns can form without the thing being in a box.

Comment: To be fair the magnetic field itself forms boundary conditions in the first two and gravity forms the boundary in the next two... boundaries don't have to be strictly physical :)

Comment: @Corey I would like to distinguish in readers' minds the difference between boundaries and forces which form structures. Examining Maxwell's equations and Newton's gravity equations, we clearly see a lack of bounds, as each of the variables in equations can go to infinity without the math 'breaking.' This, to me, implies no bounds. (Okay, stuff happens when denominators go to 0... but it's not really significant in structure-forming unless we talk about black holes.)